# Placing text label along a line on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I managed to draw a line on a canvas using html5:

```
ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
ctx.stroke();
```

This works.  I now want to "annotate" the line with text.  So basically, I want there to be custom (e.g. whatever I pass in) text appearing along the length of the line.  The difficulty is that the line can appear in any orientation (e.g. have any slope) so the text needs to be oriented accordingly.  Any ideas how to start?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have created an example of this [on my website](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_rotated_text.html). In general, you want to:

1. `translate` the context to the anchor point of the text, then
2. `rotate` the context by the amount (in radians) you desire, and then
3. `fillText` as normal.

I have included the relevant portion of my example below; <strike>I leave it as an exercise to the reader to detect when the text is upside down and handle it as desired</strike>. 
**Edit**: view the source on my site for additional code that keeps the text upright and also auto-truncates it.

```
function drawLabel( ctx, text, p1, p2, alignment, padding ){
  if (!alignment) alignment = 'center';
  if (!padding) padding = 0;

  var dx = p2.x - p1.x;
  var dy = p2.y - p1.y;   
  var p, pad;
  if (alignment=='center'){
    p = p1;
    pad = 1/2;
  } else {
    var left = alignment=='left';
    p = left ? p1 : p2;
    pad = padding / Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy) * (left ? 1 : -1);
  }

  ctx.save();
  ctx.textAlign = alignment;
  ctx.translate(p.x+dx*pad,p.y+dy*pad);
  ctx.rotate(Math.atan2(dy,dx));
  ctx.fillText(text,0,0);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

<del>*For Firefox only you also have the option of using [`mozTextAlongPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/drawing_text_using_a_canvas#mozTextAlongPath.28.29).*</del> <sub><sup>(Deprecated)</sup></sub>

Comment: I have gone through the use case linked in you post and also implemented myself, works fine except that the padding doesn't work as expected. I expected it to represent the gap between the text and the line. What was it intended for?
Also can anyone help with controlling the gap between the text and the line.

Answer (score 0):

I used it and it worked =) I just changed something so that when I make the node spin, the label is always in a good position to be read:

In my redraw function I put something like this:

```
particleSystem.eachEdge(function(edge, pt1, pt2){
      // edge: {source:Node, target:Node, length:#, data:{}}
      // pt1:  {x:#, y:#}  source position in screen coords
      // pt2:  {x:#, y:#}  target position in screen coords
      // draw a line from pt1 to pt2

     var dx = (pt2.x - pt1.x);
     var dy = (pt2.y - pt1.y);
     var p, pad;
     var alignment = "center";


      //ctx.label(edge.data.role,dx,dy,5,90,14);
      ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0, .333)";
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(pt1.x, pt1.y);
      ctx.lineTo(pt2.x, pt2.y);
      ctx.stroke();


     p = pt1;
     pad = 1/2;
     ctx.save();
 ctx.textAlign = alignment;
 ctx.translate(p.x+dx*pad,p.y+dy*pad);
     if(dx < 0)
     {
     ctx.rotate(Math.atan2(dy,dx) - Math.PI);  //to avoid label upside down
     }
     else
     {
     ctx.rotate(Math.atan2(dy,dx));

 }
     ctx.fillStyle = "black"
     ctx.fillText(edge.data.role,0,0);

 ctx.restore();
    })
```

Thanks,

Dámaris.