# CSS position text relative to static background image position

Tags: html, css, text

I'd like to position some text that resides inside of divs/spans along the shape of a static background image which sits at the bottom of the page. This text is inside divs/spans because every letter is separate due to being rotated to fit the curve of this static background image's shape.

I'd be up for alternate solutions, but I don't think I've seen a way to draw text along a vector path or anything like that, so I'd like to use relative positioning.

Comment: as of right now, i have each letter inside a div which uses absolute positioning and rotation for the effect and placement, i just figured for compatibility it may be better to do the positioning relative to the shape (background image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to use canvas ([see solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068216/placing-text-label-along-a-line-on-a-canvas)) you're better off using absolute positioning.

Comment: this is really cool, and i'm sure i could draw the line to fit my shape, but i may just end up using absolute positioning as i have it now. are there any compatibility problems if using absolute vs. relative? i've noticed other elements in my site winding up in different places when using absolute.

Comment: The wrapper needs position:relative, this sets itself as the origin point for absolutely-positioned children. This is the correct way to do this.